# Impresspages: Grouping images on single page, in ColorBox

Tags: lightbox, colorbox, impresspages

On an impressPage's site homepage, I am listing many items; each item with their own set of pictures. When an image for an item is clicked, lightBox is opened accordingly, but you can cycle through **all** the images on the page, as opposed to just cycling through a single item's set of pictures.

Is there a way to group images to each item on page, so that lightBox just cycles through images relating only to item? Thanks.

Comment: How those items are separated? Is there any logic that could be programically defined to group those pictures?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a plugin exactly for that http://market.impresspages.org/plugins/SplitColorbox